# "They could have walked out of Egypt" Source?

Tags: midrash, yetziat-mitzrayim, plagues-makkos, shemot-exodus

I have heard on multiple occasions of a Chazal that states something along the lines of:

"Had Binei Yisroel merited/been righteous enough, they could have walked out of Egypt."

There are a number of questions raised by this (such as the Makkos being made functionally superfluous) but for now I'm just looking for a textual source for this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with such a source, but maybe you were thinking of the Babylonian exile? ראויים היו ישראל ליעשות להם נס בימי עזרא כדרך שנעשה להם בימי יהושע בן נון אלא שגרם החטא (Berachot 4a)

Comment: Are you only looking for sources in hazal? Consider clarifying.

Comment: @ba I'm specifically looking for sources about Mitzraim. Possibly connected to the concept that 4/5ths of the Jews died in Egypt.

Comment: @mevaqesh I could quote myself... :) I'm deliberately casting a broad net. Is there an authoritative Jewish source that says X.

Comment: There are medrashim on "v'at arom v'eryah" that say they were devoid of mitzvot and needed to perform milah and pesach to merit the geulah.

Comment: @Loewian I'm familiar with those (fairly common haggadah Torah), but I'm more focused on the contrast of BY choosing to leave vs being forced out by Egyptians.

Comment: By the theory I cite [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/101434/), the Makkos were entirely up to the Mitzriim. It's certainly possible that the Makkos would have been superfluous (though your Midrash definitely doesn't fit with Rabbi Fohrman's theory).